# Problems with corrupt git repo

Tags: git, git-checkout

My git repo got corrupted while running a find and replace command (See here: [Git reset failing after find and replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14564936/git-reset-failing-after-find-and-replace)). So I deleted some pack files about which git told me that there were not reachable. So I ran rm ./.git/index, git reset. When running git commit, I got this message :

```
fatal: corrupt tree sha $someSHA
```

Finally git fsck, my working directory went clean and I was able to commit. The pb now is that when I run git checkout some_other_branch, I got this message

```
fatal: unable to read tree $someSHA
```

(The $someSHA appearing are the same). Someone could help me ?

#### Edit 1 :

when I run git fsck --full, I get a serie of

```
error: refs/remotes/repo0/master does not point to a valid object!
error: refs/remotes/repo1/new-version does not point to a valid object!
...
```

then a serie of

```
broken link from    tree d935b909f76ea92728d71038d0a67384353e65e1
              to    blob 05b97658ebd47fee25b76d80ac76cbd07d77961d
...
```

and then some missing blobs...

#### Edit 2 :

I ran git log --raw --all --full-history -- subdir/my-file, and I get

```
error: refs/remotes/repo0/master does not point to a valid object!
error: refs/remotes/repo1/new-version does not point to a valid object!
...
error: Could not read 9096eb9d9dcbdf15a04e0a7c78a3744936f82ac7
fatal: cannot simplify commit 8dfd8e3d5b698dc979300d93d8e89a757abf6ec6 (because of 9096eb9d9dcbdf15a04e0a7c78a3744936f82ac7)
```

#### Edit 3 :

I ran `git fsck --full`, the I get numerous lines as so

```
error: packfile .git/objects/pack/pack-fbfd8042e1e96bf5ffff88f9b5a230b8f5e4d4c4.pack does not match index
fatal: packfile .git/objects/pack/pack-fbfd8042e1e96bf5ffff88f9b5a230b8f5e4d4c4.pack cannot be accessed
...
```

when running `git checkout` to another branch I got numerous messages as so :

```
error: packfile .git/objects/pack/pack-3e7a0c040a5e3d1c21b91256d583424d82a59706.pack does not match index
warning: packfile .git/objects/pack/pack-3e7a0c040a5e3d1c21b91256d583424d82a59706.pack cannot be accessed
....
fatal: unable to read tree 2ad71d368b65eff0b6fec1ef72c6fdde6e80edad
```

#### Edit 4 :

following the suggested answer, I unpacked the files and when I checked out, I got 
some lines as so :

```
error: packfile .git/objects/pack/pack-fbfd8042e1e96bf5ffff88f9b5a230b8f5e4d4c4.pack does not match index
warning: packfile .git/objects/pack/pack-fbfd8042e1e96bf5ffff88f9b5a230b8f5e4d4c4.pack cannot be accesse....
```

and then a serie of lines beginning with

```
 error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
.idea_local_work/.name
.idea_local_work/libraries/sass_stdlib.xml
.idea_local_work/scopes/scope_settings.xml
... and then aborting
```

Comment: You did WHAT?!?!? Why did you think that deleting packfiles would be  a good idea? Do you have a backup of these packfiles or did you push your stuff anywhere?

Comment: Yes I have them in some backups, what can I do with them ?

Comment: @Chronial I have no problem with loosing all data in my current branch. I just want to get back another branch. Do you thin k it is possible ?

Comment: Put your packfiles back in your repo, git needs them :). Or did you corrupt them by changing their content? Do you want to get back to branch that you already pushed?

Comment: Indeed I have the pack files in my backup. I want to leave the branch I am currently on and I can loose it because I have it in some remote repo, and then go to another critical branch, that I don't have in my remote but only in my local. You think there's still some hope ?

Comment: Yes – put the packfiles back where they belong, run `git fsck --full` and then try to check out your other branch. Update your question with the output of `git fsck` and the checkout.

Comment: @Chronial, I update my post and it didn't work

Comment: You put pack the files you corrupted by your search-and-replace, right? Have you tried to fix them by undoing your search-and-replace?

Comment: sure I tried to undo the replace and fin but it didn't work... the situation is too bad...

Comment: Looks like a bug. Consider creating new ticket to git development team

Answer (score 40, accepted):

First: Make a backup of your `.git` directory in case you corrupt things more in this process. Then:

- Put back the best version of the packfiles you have available.
- For each of the corrupt packfiles, run:

  ```
  mv .git/objects/pack/pack-**yourpack**.pack oldpack
  git unpack-objects -r < oldpack
  ```
- Run `git fsck --full` and `git checkout` again, give us the output.
- Looks like now you should be able to check out, but you will have to run `git checkout -f **yourbranch**`, as you have changes in your working dir that are not yet committed. These changes will get lost when you run `git checkout -f`, though.

Comment: I began to run your command, and when putting this git unpack-objects -r < oldpack,  I get a bunch of errors, is it normal: packfile .git/objects/pack/pack-3e7a0c040a5e3d1c21b91256d583424d82a59706.pack does not match index
warning: packfile .git/objects/pack/pack-3e7a0c040a5e3d1c21b91256d583424d82a59706.pack cannot be accessed...

Comment: Did the command run nevertheless or did it stop because of these errors?

Comment: Yes it ran. I got the message I reported in the precedent message and then finishing by Unpacking objects: 100% (761/761), done. Should I continue unpacking the files with the same oldpack file ?

Comment: Yes, unpack all the packfiles that are reported as corrupt. You can name them oldpack2 etc if you prefer.

Comment: I updated my post, should I unpack the same error: packfile .git/objects/pack/pack-fbfd8042e1e96bf5ffff88f9b5a230b8f5e4d4c4.pack ?

Comment: if you still get the error you did not mv the packfile away as per my first line, did you?

Comment: So this file didn' appear at first, but I unpacked it. Now I have the messages telling me 'Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout'. Should I run git fsck --full again or commiting ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23528/discussion-between-chronial-and-newben)

Comment: (added some more info to the chat)

Comment: Wrote the script to unpack all such "unaccessible" packfiles: https://gist.github.com/kirikaza/6178695#file-fix-git-packfiles-sh.

Comment: Had to run `git unpack-objects -r < oldpack` instead of `git-unpack-objects -r < oldpack`

Comment: You're the man! Thank you, it worked well. I almost resorted to recloning. Awesome!

Answer (score -1):

Rewrite this file with the same file from another .git copy of this repository.