# Getting the error "pack cannot be mapped: Invalid argument" why?

Tags: git

I am having trouble with my git repo running on bitbucket servers through source tree.
I accidentally added a commit which pushed me over the 4gb limit. I tried reversing the commit, which didn't reduce my 4.7gb repo size.

I then tried doing a git reset --hard HEAD^ to set my head to the previous commit which then removed the large commit from the history view, but the repo size did not reduce.

Running git gc --aggressive gives the following output:

```
git gc --aggressive
Enumerating objects: 100305, done.
Counting objects: 100% (100305/100305), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
fatal: packfile .git/objects/pack/pack-b863c7c7a902d99d1783551cecaac2264ea22bed.pack cannot be mapped: Invalid argument
fatal: failed to run repack
```

I also tried counting Atlassian support but unfortunately, I'm just a solo student and don't have a commercial license so they said they were unable to help.

I'm at a loss on what else to try, any ideas? Thank you for your time.

Comment: This is nothing to do with atlasian or source tree. Git is a [open source product](https://git-scm.com/about) that atlasian use in their own products

Comment: Sounds like your repo is corrupt, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14569172/problems-with-corrupt-git-repo Delete it and re-clone it

Comment: Worth noting that *pack-b863c7c7a902d99d1783551cecaac2264ea22bed.pack* is a file Git uses internally. Have you by any chance been manually tampering with the `.git` folder?

Comment: @Liam I realize that this is solely for git, just figured i'd give the full picture of my situation

Comment: What OS are you on?  What version of Git are you using? Is it 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: @bk2204 I am on windows 10.0.19043 in 64 bit

Comment: @bk2204 I am on git 2.26.2.windows.1
Liam I didn't touch the .git folder, at least not manually. I'm giving that link a shot